# Navigator.push() inside showdialog not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Trying to navigate to a new screen using Navigator.push(), but it's not working.
I have created a custom class to show AlertDialog and call the class with the object to show alertDialog

```
_customerAlertDialog.showConfirmAlertDialog(
   context: context,
   title: "Login In",
   subTitle: "You need to login to purchase.",
   onTapResponse: (bool val) async {
     if (val) {
       /// close AlertDialog
       Navigator.of(context).pop();
       Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
       print("show the login screen");

     } else {
       //TODO : when user click no.
     }
   });
```

navigator.pop() is working,
print statement is  working,
but  Navigator.push is not working. Also tried this:

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `context` object that you use in `Navigator.of(context).pop()` isn't aware of the dialog.

If your custom alert dialog is calling `showDialog`, consider passing on the `BuildContext` object that is returned by the `builder`:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext ctx) { 
    // ctx is a context object that will be aware of the dialog
    // consider passing this along to onTapResponse as an argument
  },
);
```

Then you can use that `BuildContext` to get the navigator that will be able to close the dialog:

```
onTapResponse: (BuildContext ctx, bool val) async {
  if (val) {
    // close AlertDialog
    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
    Navigator.of(ctx).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
    print("show the login screen");
  } else {
    //TODO : when user click no.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

changes the context.

So, after pop(), same context does not work for

```
Navigator.of(context).push
```

So either simply use only Navigator.push(context).push i.e. no need to call pop as dialog can automatically pop when moving to different screen

or Second option is to use

```
Navigator.pop(context, [some boolean value here]);
```

like return true with pop.
And use that value of pop with a condition that if result is true, then push to different screen.

example:

```
var result = await _customerAlertDialog.showConfirmAlertDialog();
if(result) => Navigator.of(context).push();
```